# Do i have to use Session Storage or LocalStorage : javascript AWS

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, session, local-storage

I have below scenario

Page 1 has a link, when user clicks on it, it gets navigated to portal page with page reload. So just before navigation, a JSON object is created

The size of this object comes around 4KB roughly.

Sample object

```
let obj = {
    "date":"12/31/2018",
    "year":"2019",
    "zip":"93252",
    "members":[
    {
        "sdf":true,
        "age":21,
        "fdssss":false,
        "aaaa":false,
        "fdss":null,
        "fsdfsd":[
            "ADULT"
        ]
    },
    {
        "sdf":true,
        "age":21,
        "fdssss":false,
        "aaaa":false,
        "fdss":null,
        "fsdfsd":[
            "ADULT"
        ]
    }
}
```

There is a **back link** from that portal page, on clicking page will be navigated back to Page 1 with a page reload.

So when the page is navigated back, I need the created JSON object back again. I need it only for that session or the data should be persistent even if the page is reloaded.

1. Do I have to use `localStorage`? If i store the object in `localStorage`, at what point i should clear the storage? How should I handle between different users?
2. Do I have to use `sessionStorage`? what will be the scope of the data availability

I'm using AWS service.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Comment: @mplungjan i am using AWS. And for my scenrio, is it good to use `SessionStorage `or `LocalStorage`?

Comment: sessionStorage seems to be enough for your use.

Answer (score 3):

**Q1:**
you can have `localStorage`, and you should handle it at the code when first page loaded and you can delete it when user do signout or login, storage is about browser not user, if there are some users behind one computer at different times you must clear all data manually.

**Q2:**
you can also have `sessionStorage`, per tab and will be removed by closing browser.

**in details:**

This is depends on your scenario which means `localStorage` used for long time but `sessionStorage` used when you need to store something temporary.

but the important thing about `sessionStorage` is that it is exist per tab if you close tab and windows the `sessionStorage` completely removed, it used for critical data such as username and password whereas `localStorage` is used to shared data whole the browser.

`localStorage` has no expiration date, and it gets cleared only by code, or clearing the browser cache or locally stored data whereas `sessionStorage` object stores data only for a session, meaning that the data is stored until the browser (or tab) is closed.

at the end I suggest you to use `localStorage` because you may want to share that data whole the browser event after closing browser and you can store more data, in the other side there are limitation about them, when you are used storage you should handle them manually and take care.

suppose:

```
function removeStorage()
{
   var obj = localStorage.getItem('obj');
   if(obj !== null)
       localStorage.removeItem('obj') 
}
```

and in login or logout success action call `removeStorage()` and in Page1 load have something like below:

```
var obj = localStorage.getItem('obj');
if(obj !== null)
{
   ....
   //show the obj in label or do what you want with it 
   ...
}
```